# For the circuit shown find the Thevenin’s equivalent circuit between terminals A and B

Tags: thevenin

Here I began with Vth making mesh equations :

48-6I<sub>1</sub>-12(I<sub>1</sub>+I<sub>2</sub>)=0

12(I<sub>1</sub>+I<sub>2</sub>)+4<sub>2</sub>+8I<sub>2</sub>=0

With which I get I<sub>1</sub>=4A & I<sub>2</sub>=-2A

Then I considered the open circuit part AB to use the 2 mesh currents there which is where I do not understand how to proceed.

For Rth also I am getting an error as well.

[image]

Comment: I get Rth = 6.667 ohms. What did you get and what was the correct answer listed as? I get Vth(AB) = 32 volts.

Comment: Rth given is 4ohms I got about 5.333 though and yeah Vth is correct can you explain how you got the Vth

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my mistake Rth is 4 ohms. You don't really need to make mesh equations to solve this.

Comment: Could you explain it

Answer (score 1):

Start with this: -

[image]

The impedance into the node marked with a red arrow is \$\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{6}}\$ = 4 ohms.

And this is in series with another 4 ohms when you look at node B. That makes 8 ohms but, there is a resistor to node C\$^1\$ of 8 ohms. So the total impedance between B and A is: -

\$\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}}\$ = 4 ohms.

---

\$^1\$ node C connects to node A when analysing impedances because voltage sources short to zero volts. Can you get the voltage next yourself?

Comment: yeah actually I got to the Rth part myself later on still stuck with the voltage though getting it as 28V somehow

Comment: Work on the voltage at the junction of the three restores where my arrow points.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the Thevenin's voltage across AB terminals

1- We need to calculate the current in the closed circuit that has 6 ohm resistance which is in series with the parallel combination of 12 ohm resistance and the series combination of 4 & 8 ohm resistances.

2- Thus, the equivalent resistance that is connected to 6 ohm resistance becomes (8+4) parallel with 12 = 12*12/12+12 = 144/24= 6ohm.

3- The current in the closed circuit is I = 48/(6+6)= 4A

4- Using current divider formula, we hence, can calculate the current through the series combination of (4+8) resistances which is I = (12/(12+4+8))*4= 2A

5- Therefore, the voltage drop across 4 ohm resistance will be = 2*4= 8V

6- Using the voltage divider formula, we can calculate the voltage at the node between the 6 ohm resistance and the equivalent resistance of 6 ohm, V = (6/6+6)*48 = 24V.

7- Now, to calculate the voltage at B terminal, V@B = V@24-Voltage drop across 4 ohm resistance, hence V@B = 24-2*4=24-8= 16 V.

8- Finally, the Thevenin's voltage across AB= The voltage at node D (same as A) - voltage at terminal B = 48-16= 32V